# Proof of Darboux Theorem in topology

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

$I$ is an open interval in $\mathbb{R}$, $f:I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a differentiable function. $T=\{(x,y)\in I\times I:x<y\}$. Let $g : T → \mathbb{R}$ be the function defined by
$g(x, y) = \frac{f(x) − f(y)}{x − y}$ Prove:

1) $T$ is a connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the standard topology.

2) Prove that $g(T) ⊆ f'
(I) ⊆ \overline{g(T)}$.

3) Show that $f'(I)$ is an interval.

My thoughts:

1) $T$ is path-connected, so it's connected.

2) No idea. $g$ is the derivative of $f$, so it's continuous as $f$ is ($f$ is continuous as it's differentiable). I can see that this would imply that $f'(I)$ would be connected, though the converse isn't necessarily true. How can I show the given claim?

3) Point 2) would show that $f'(I)$ is connected, which would be enough to say it's an interval.

So it's point 2) I need help with. Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2) $g$ is not the derivative of $f$. However, we can use the Mean Value Theorem to show that $g(T)\subset f^\prime(I)$. The other inclusion *is* the definition of the derivative $$f^\prime(y) =\lim_{x\to y}\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}.$$
3) Based on (1) and (2), I would try to show that $g$ is continuous on $T$.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

2) From the MVT: $\forall (x,y)\in T,\exists c\in I: f'(c)=g(x,y)$. Hence the first inclusion. 

For the second inclusion: $\forall y\in I,f'(y)=\lim_{x\to y}g(x,y)$, which is in $\overline{g(T)}$ as the closure of a set contains the limits of sequences in that set.

3) You're right, $g$ certainly isn't the limit of $f$. So, I'm a bit stuck. I have a function which goes from a connected set to $\mathbb{R}^2$ (which is connected), although this doesn't imply that it's continuous. Any hints?

Comment: Since $f$ is continuous, it should be easy to show that $g$ is continuous: take a sequence $(x_n,y_n)\to (x,y)$ and show that $g(x_n,y_n)\to g(x,y)$.

Comment: Ok, I can show that. Although I didn't realize that $((x\rightarrow x_n)\Rightarrow (f(x_n)\rightarrow f(x))$ implied that $f$ is continuous - I only knew that the converse was true

Comment: Oops - that's obvious, just from the definition, ignore my last comment. Thanks!